# cordova deploy on real android device

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

I created a sample cordova 3.4.0 android app. `cordova emulate android` deploys the app onto the adt emulated android device. How do I deploy it onto a real android device directly? I have USB debugging enabled on the device.

Answer (score 1):

Plug the device into your computer and run `cordova run android`.

This can be found in the [Cordova Android Platform Guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide_deploy_to_device).